# Only Phone number is to be selected

Tags: android, sms

Hi I have the following code. nOw I need only phone number to be taken into the autocomplete text box...how to do that

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPeopleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    PopulatePeopleList();
    mTxtPhoneNo = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.mmWhoNo);

    mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mPeopleList, R.layout.custcontview,
            new String[] {"Name","Phone","Type"}, new int[] {R.id.ccontName,R.id.ccontNo,R.id.ccontType});

    mTxtPhoneNo.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

public void PopulatePeopleList() {

    mPeopleList.clear();

    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    while (people.moveToNext()) {
        String contactName = people.getString(people
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        String contactId = people.getString(people
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String hasPhone = people
                .getString(people
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

        if ((Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) > 0)) {

            // You know have the number so now query it like this
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = " + contactId, null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {

                // store numbers and display a dialog letting the user
                // select which.
                String phoneNumber = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                String numberType = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

                Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();

                NamePhoneType.put("Name", contactName);
                NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber);

                if (numberType.equals("0"))
                    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Work");
                else if (numberType.equals("1"))
                    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Home");
                else if (numberType.equals("2"))
                    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Mobile");
                else
                    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Other");

                // Then add this map to the list.
                mPeopleList.add(NamePhoneType);
            }
            phones.close();
        }
    }
    people.close();

    startManagingCursor(people);
}
```

}

It returns like Name=xyz.Type=Mobile,Number=1234 in this format....
I need only the number to be taken and use that number for further of my program where to add the code in order to get the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only use this line

```
String phoneNumber = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


            NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber);
```

you are putting all the data including name, type.. only put phone and see

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code **

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/AfromACT"
android:layout_width="150px"
android:layout_height="40px"
android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
android:layout_marginTop="15px"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:textColor="#000000" 
android:singleLine="true"
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
android:paddingLeft="5px"
```

android:inputType="phone"
    android:textSize="17px" />

Comment: not the inputtype .. he is asking to show the number in autocomplete